# Why is this double division returning a truncated number?

Tags: c++

I have been struggling with this for some time and I can guess that it's something silly like the way in which I am using size_type or my functions however whenever I have an even input and I try to find the median, the program will divide the two middle values and output a truncated number without the decimal digits which I need.

The program aims to take a mapping of strings and assign them to the value that is a vector of doubles. This is so you can keep track of the digits entered under the same key.

I also added a picture of what my console looks like. From the output, I would like the median to be 5.5.

I tried casting everything to float individually but that did not cut it either. My suspicion is that it has to do with the structure of the size_type data type but I am not sure.

**Main**

```
#include "Util.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>::iterator mapStrVectorIt;

int main()
{

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> dict;
    double x;
    std::string str;
    Util util;

    //Take in the inputs from the user in the format: string double, add the double to the respective vector
    while (std::cin >> str >> x) {
        dict[str].push_back(x);
    }

    //Outputs each key and the value/s associated with it
    for (mapStrVectorIt it = dict.begin(); it != dict.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it).first << ": ";
        std::vector<double> itVector = (*it).second;
        for (auto i = itVector.cbegin(); i != itVector.cend(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << *i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << "-----------------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';

    //Looks through every single vector in the map and calculates the median
    for (mapStrVectorIt it = dict.begin(); it != dict.end(); ++it)
    {
        
        std::vector<double> itVector = (*it).second;
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << (*it).first << ": median = " << util.median(itVector);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

**Util.h**

```
#ifndef GUARD_stats_h
#define GUARD_stats_h

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Util
{
public:
    Util() {};
    int median(std::vector<double>& v);
};
#endif
```

**Util.cpp**

```
#include "Util.h"
int Util::median(std::vector<double>& v) {

    typedef std::vector<double>::size_type sizeT;
    sizeT size = v.size();


    if (size == 0)
    {
        return 0;  // Undefined, really.
    }
    else if (size == 1)
    {
        return *(v.begin());
    }
    else
    {
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        if (size % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << " even ";
            return (v[size / 2 - 1] + v[size / 2]) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return v[size / 2];
        }
    }

    
}
```

[image]

Comment: `int Util::median(std::vector<double>& v)`. Key thing there is the `int` return type.

Comment: Wow...it's been a long night, thank you so much.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why we like [mre]s. When you got the program down to something that looked like `int median() ( return 3.24; } int main() ( std::cout << median; }` you probably would have seen the mistake yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan Pierson kindly mentioned, the median was declared with an int return type...